# pdf to txt convertion in qt or c++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, qt, qt4

Hi
How can I convert pdf to txt with qt ? 
if there isn't way to do this , Is there any library for c++ that convert pdf files to txt files ?
thanks.
**My os is windows7 and my ide is visual studio 2008**

Comment: To be reliable, that would involve parsing the PDF file format.  Depending on the text encoding, just looking through the file for stuff that looks like plain text might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foxit sells their PDF code as a library. I use it, and it's great.

http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/sdk/dll/

You may know them for their very popular free Acrobat Reader alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Not all pdf files contain text. When getting text from them you might need to use OCR. It is possible to build an printer driver for a virtual printer and get the text by capturing undocumented windows messages. To my knowledge there is no easy foolproof way to do this.

Comment: The printer hack sounds like a pain. It would be far easier to "print to file" and parse the result.